# Permutation/combination problem with 'coins'

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve a 'number of possible outcomes' problem. Here it be:

There are 7 unique and completely different ‘coins’ – each has 2 sides that are again each unique and completely different from all of the others. In essence there are 14 unique things assigned to 7 discreet objects. The coins would be randomly assigned a separate position – there are 7 unique positions. How many possible ways could those 7 unique coins (each with 2 sides) be combined?

For the sake of explanation, imagine the 'coins' are broken out like this:

Coin 1 (A/a); Coin 2 (B/b); Coin 3 (C/c); Coin 4 (D/d); Coin 5 (E/e); Coin 6 (F/f); Coin 7 (G/g)

And you would take those 7 coins and randomly select and flip 1, then the next, then the next, until all 7 coins are in all seven positions. How many possible outcomes are there? Thanks in advance!

-c

Comment: You may find it easier to work on such problems if you spend some time to find a clear, concise way to describe what's going on. In particular, your paragraph describing the coins is not only quite long, but it introduces extraneous and unwieldy information. I would simply label the coins (if you even need to label them after having defined them) like so: A/a, B/b, ..., G/g.

Comment: Hey thanks for the stylistic reccomendation - I'm new here, so not very adept at the maths or conventions of this site, but I will definitely edit it. Any thoughts to the answer though?

Comment: My pleasure. As for answering the question, simplify it first. Suppose the coins only have a single face, so A, B, ..., G. How many ways are there to arrange them?

Comment: Guidelines: How many ways are there to arrange the $7$ coins in order without any regard to the sides? And _for each_ one of those arrangements, how many arrangements of the _different sides_ are there?

Comment: I'm imagining it's like a factorial 7*6*5*4*3*2*1, only with unique coins. So my thought is that it's actually: 14*12*10*8*6*4*2 = 645120. Just not 100% that that's correct.

Comment: And there you go! You could consider writing it as $7!\cdot2^7$.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Codesigned I would go ahead and answer your own question with that solution ($7! \cdot 2^7$), so this question isn't marked as unanswered.

Comment: will do! Thanks again!!